# Not able to filter out the array of object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61dbab7f0beb8c8075370217"),
    "name" : "Question 2",
    "answers" : [
        {
            "text" : "something 1",
            "isDeleted" : false
        },
        {
            "text" : "something 2",
            "isDeleted" : true
        },
        {
            "text" : "something 2",
            "isDeleted" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this kind of document where I want to find all answers objects which have `isDeleted` is `false`.

Comment: Can you be more clear? You want to find all documents which have an `answers` field with at least one`isDeleted: false`? Or do you want to just end up with a list of just the answers themselves that have `isDeleted: false`? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter`

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  answers: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$answers",
      cond: {
        $eq: [
          "$$this.isDeleted",
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  name :1
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y8CLtsvjEZn)**